# Segment button in toolbar appearing left aligned

Tags: android, sencha-touch-2

The segment button in toolbar is appearing aligned left in Android device, but in my chrome browser and iOS device its appearing at center.
How to make in Android also appear at center.

Comment: How about you show us some code. Any jS or CSS you're using would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show me some code. It works for me in Android as well.

Only thing you need to do is add xtype:spacer before and after segmentedbutton item.

```
items : [{ xtype : 'spacer'},

         {xtype : 'segmentedbutton', items:[]},

         {xtype : 'spacer'}]
```

This should work, whatever browser you use.

Comment: thanks, this one fixed my problem. i think in Android is not able to adjust the item automatically as chrome browser and iOS does.